# How to Package, archive, collect, copy or assemble test dependencies in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

Can't seem to find out how to do this very simple thing in SBT: I'd like to package (or pack/assemble/archive/copy) all of the dependencies needed to run tests. Ideally this would include all the dependency jars and the project classes jar in some tar/gz/zip, but simply copying them into a single folder so I can then easily zip them up would be great. All I've found so far is the ability to simply list the classpath ('show test:dependencyClasspath') but this leaves me having to write a script to copy or archive them. sbt-pack works great for the regular runtime classpath dependencies but couldn't get it to work with any test dependencies and had the same issue with sbt-assembly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can reuse most parts of sbt-pack by overriding a few selected settings to refer to the test classpath.

In your build, add :

```
packSettings

packAllClasspaths <<= (thisProjectRef, buildStructure) flatMap getFromAllProjects(dependencyClasspath in Test),
packAllUnmanagedJars <<= (thisProjectRef, buildStructure, packExclude) flatMap getFromSelectedProjects(unmanagedJars in Test),
packLibJars <<= (thisProjectRef, buildStructure, packExclude) flatMap getFromSelectedProjects(packageBin in Test)
```

However, you will also need to copy [those methods](https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack/blob/develop/src/main/scala/xerial/sbt/Pack.scala#L302-319) from sbt-pack code to make it work.
This may not be exactly be the cleanest way to do it, but you avoid re-implementing the packaging process yourself.

IMO, your best bet would be use [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager), which is more flexible on how you define your package and the file you put into it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but I was hoping to find something that would just work and am still very surprised that I can't seem to find one. Also, this solution appears to include test dependencies in *every* package and I need to be able to specify it. Finally, the purpose of sbt-native-packager appears to be for creating packages for native packing systems and requiring these for installation of some java code is unnecessary and inflexible.

Comment: Well, packaging tests is something understandable, but not exactly **that** common. Those plugins are first designed to produce applications bundles, with scripts to run those applications. You can customize them to suit your needs, but do not expect plugins that does exactly what you want out of the box. On the topic of sbt-native-packager, I can assure that you can also you produce zips : http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html

Comment: Huh, that link talks about 'universal packaging' and that it '...may require manual labor to set up.' Maybe if I gave it more than 2 minutes I could figure it out. It still appears somewhat complex to configure, but maybe that's just because I've never gotten into SBT in depth. I've just used SBT to specify dependencies, resolvers, eclipse project file generation, and packaging. So it appears if I want this functionality I'll have to build it, which is fine, just don't have time to pick up SBT particulars now.